# How to retrieve an element inside an ArrayList value in a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm new to Java and I'm struggling to figure out something trivial.

I have a `HashMap` with keys of type `String` and values of type `ArrayList <String>`, and it returns something like this:

```
dict = {Color=[Blue, Purple]}
```

I'm struggling to figure out how I can grab a specific element from the array in the value of dict. Like if I got `dict.value[0]`, it would return the string 'Blue'.

I've tried doing:

```
Object values = dict.values().toArray[0];
```

and I assumed that since I changed it to an array, I could do something like `values.get(0)` to get the first element, but that doesn't work because values is type `Object`. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Let me know if you still have questions after reviewing my answer. I feel like you might need to understand more about *Java as a strongly typed programming language*.

Answer (score 3):

if your `HashMap` is like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> myColorsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And after populating the map is like:

```
{Red=[firstRed, secondRed, thirdRed], Blue=[firstBlue, secondBlue, thirdBlue]}
```

then you can retrieve **Blue**'s key value (a `List`) like:

```
String blueFirstElement = myColorsMap.get("Blue").get(0); // --> will give first element of List<String> stored against Blue key.
```

To get collection of all keys in your map (or "dictionary"):

```
myColorsMap.keySet();
```

will give:

```
[Red, Blue]
```

When you do:

```
Object values = dict.values().toArray[0];
```

First, this is wrong. What you were trying to do is this:

```
Object values = dict.values().toArray();
```

Which returns `Object[]` and it is ambiguous. No need to do that. Java's `Map` interface and `HashMap` implementation have a lot of utility methods for you to iterate and retrieve your values.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `.get()` on map to get the ArrayList using key

```
List<String> colors = dict.get("Color");
```

Then use `.get()` on list to get the element using index

```
String color = colors.get(0);
```

You can do this in one line this way

```
String color = dict.get("Color").get(0);
```

You are trying with `dict.values().toArray[0]` which is wrong syntax thats the problem. `dict.values()` will return `Collection<List<String>>`, you can get List of values this way

```
List<List<String>> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>(colorsMap.values());
```

Then you can access each value by index using `.get()`

```
List<String> colors = listOfValues.get(0);
```

*Note* : HashMap don't store any order.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to type of `java.util.List`, and then you can get value through index.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>(2);
    map.put("color", Arrays.asList("blue", "yellow", "green", "white"));
    map.put("size", Arrays.asList("small", "medium", "large"));
    List<String> o = (List<String>) map.values().toArray()[0];
    System.out.println(o.get(0));               //output is 'blue'

    List<String> s = (List<String>) map.values().toArray()[1];
    System.out.println(s.get(1));               //output is 'medium'
}
```